# When I click on calendar, I need to pass id to server and fetch date from database. If any response then I need to mark red color on calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I click on `dateFrom` calendar, I need to pass `data-id` to server and fetch some date from database. If any date response, I need to mark red color and not select that date on calendar.

At-present when I click `data-id` is passing to server and getting response correctly. But I don't know how that response get in `datepicker()` and mark as disable date in calendar. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

[image: Please check this image]

**Style**

```
<style>
    .markholiday .ui-state-default
    {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

**html**

```
<div class="form-group row calendar" data-id="5799f281049ac12422000033">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateFrom hasDatepicker" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" placeholder="Arrival" readonly="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateTo hasDatepicker" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" placeholder="Departure" readonly="">
         </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group row calendar" data-id="5799f281049ac12422000034">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateFrom hasDatepicker" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" placeholder="Arrival" readonly="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateTo hasDatepicker" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" placeholder="Departure" readonly="">
         </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group row calendar" data-id="5799f281049ac12422000035">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateFrom hasDatepicker" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" placeholder="Arrival" readonly="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateTo hasDatepicker" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" placeholder="Departure" readonly="">
         </div>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
$( ".dateFrom" ).on('click', function(){
                var dataId  = $(this).parent().parent().data("id");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/calendar',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { dataId: dataId },
                    success : function(response) {
                        var data  = response.disableDates; //["2018-01-31", "2018-02-20"];
                    }
                });
            });


            var array  = data // here data is not getting  
            $( ".dateFrom" ).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "dd.mm.y",
                            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                return [true, (array.indexOf(string) == -1) ? "" : "markholiday"];
                            }
                        });
```

**Controller**

```
$seasons           = Season::where('cabin_id', $request->dataId)->get();
// after some process I am getting result
return response()->json(['disableDates' => $disableDates], 200); //["2018-01-31", "2018-02-20"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
success : function(response) {
  var disableddates = DisableSpecificDates(response.disableDates);
}


function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
var m = getMonth();
var d = getDate();
var y = getFullYear();
var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y ;
for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {
   if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {
      return [false];
     }
  }

 }

 $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting error when I click on text box. "Uncaught TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Update answer try it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dateFrom").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.y",
        });

        $("body").on('mousedown', ".dateFrom", function() {
            var dataId = $(this).parent().parent().data("id");
            var $this = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/calendar',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { dataId: dataId },
                success: function(response) {
                    var array = response.disableDates; //["2018-01-31", "2018-02-20"];
                    $this.datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", function(date) {
                        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        return [true, "", (array.indexOf(string) == -1) ? "" : "markholiday"];
                    });

                    $this.datepicker( "show" );
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined".

Comment: Try to console it

Comment: console.dir($(".dateFrom").data("datepicker"))

Comment: I am using jquery ui datepicker. The result is undefined

Comment: This answer is using jqueryui 1.12.1

Comment: I have added as per your code but not working `success: function(response) { var array = response.disableDates; //["2018-01-31", "2018-02-20"];
$(".dateFrom").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "dd.mm.y"
                    });

                    $(".dateFrom").data("datepicker").settings.beforeShowDay =  function(date) {
                        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        return [true, (array.indexOf(string) == -1) ? "" : "markholiday"];
                    }
                }`

Comment: I change the setting method, try it

Comment: Thank you. When I click on text box, calendar showing but immediately hiding and showing again.

Comment: try to remove "$this.datepicker( "show" )" and try again

Comment: I tried but calendar showing but immediately hiding

Comment: Maybe you can get the "disableDates" first then print the html

Comment: use "ajax" have some delay, it's will rebuild datepicker when success and hide